# LinkedIn Reshare ugcPost using API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to reshare a ugcPost using V2 API.

I have used v2/shares to get this done. I am getting Internal Server Error.

Anybody tried this, please let me know if this is feasible at all?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am running into the same issue.  I keep getting a 500 error.  
```"author": "urn:li:person:<uid>",
      "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
      "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
          "shareMediaCategory": "URN_REFERENCE",
          "shareCommentary": {
            "text": "This is LinkedIn Resharing"
          },
          "media": [
            {
              "media": "urn:li:share:6577220936284545024",
              "status": "READY"
            }
          ],
   ```  
Reg share is working fine for me.

Comment: I am actually using the `/ugcPosts` endpoint.  As I mentioned above regular share of social post and images it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should add X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0 in your headers

Comment: Do you have this working with that header?  If so do you mind elaborating on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got this figure out but I spent a while on it so I wanted to throw this out there unless anyone else runs into this.  For me I was not using the responseContext to reference the parent post.  This is what ended up working for me.

```
  "author": "urn:li:person:#{uid of user}",
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",

  #this part here
  "responseContext": {
    "parent": "urn:li:share:6577220936284545024",
    "root": "urn:li:share:6577220936284545024"
   },

   "specificContent": {
     "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
       "shareMediaCategory": "NONE",
        "shareCommentary": {
          "text": "Comment here about the reshared post."
        },
        "media": [],
        "shareCategorization": {}
      }
    },
    "visibility": {
      "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
```

And headers should be

```
    {
      "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}",
      "Content-Type" => 'application/json',
      "X-Restli-Protocol-Version" => "2.0.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A reshare of a ugcPost should use "responseContext" as found in the schema within the ugcPost documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#schema

Here is a sample call for resharing a ugcPost:

cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts' \
--header 'x-li-format: json' \
--header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
--data-raw '{  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
  },
  "specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
      "shareMediaCategory": "NONE",
      "shareCommentary": {
        "text": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "responseContext": {
    "parent": "urn:li:ugcPost:123",
    "root": "urn:li:ugcPost:123"
  },
  "author": "urn:li:person:123"
}'
```

Ruby:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port);
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["x-li-format"] = "json"
request["X-Restli-Protocol-Version"] = "2.0.0"
request["Content-Type"] = ["application/json", "application/json"]
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
request.body = payload.to_json

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;
$request->setRequestUrl('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts');
$request->setRequestMethod('POST');
$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->append('{
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    },
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareMediaCategory": "NONE",
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "responseContext": {
        "parent": "urn:li:ugcPost:123",
        "root": "urn:li:ugcPost:123"
    },
    "author": "urn:li:person:123"
}');
$request->setBody($body);
$request->setOptions(array());
$request->setHeaders(array(
  'x-li-format' => 'json',
  'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
));
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();
echo $response->getBody();
```